# Why is my list empty?

Tags: c#, list

Class Administration:

```
namespace AnimalShelter
{
  class Administration
  {
    private List<Animal> animalList;

    public Administration()
    {
        animalList = new List<Animal>();
    }

    public bool AddAnimal(Animal animal)
    {
        bool status = false;
        foreach (Animal TempAnimal in animalList)
        {
            if (TempAnimal.ChipRegistrationNumber == animal.ChipRegistrationNumber)
            {
                status = false;
            }
            else
            {
                status = true;
                animalList.Add(animal);
            }
        }
        return status;
    }
```

As you can see here, I've made a list, initializing it in the constuctor.

In the AddAnimal method I'm looping through the list if the number is the same as the other. If the number matches, you cannot add another animal with that specific ChipNumber.

Now for my Form:

```
 private Administration administration;

 public AdministrationForm()
 {
     administration = new Administration();
 }

 private void btnCreateAnimal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
            Animal cat1 = new Cat(params..);
            if (administration.AddAnimal(cat1))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Following animal has succesfully been
                added: " + Environment.NewLine + cat1.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Animal with this chipnumber already exists.
                Please Choose another one.");
            }
 }
```

So in here I'm just easily stating  if the method is true, create the animal. If  it's false, don't add the animal.

Question: The list always remains empty if I add animals to the list. It's as if it constantly refreshes/clears the list. What am I doing wrong here?

Hope it's understandable this way, else let me know!

Comment: Why do you have foreach loop in AddAnimal method?

Comment: @Viru I'm using it because I have to check for every animal in the list if the chipnumber has the same chipnumber that has been filled in for registration. Hope that makes sense

Comment: When you new up the `Administration`, `animalList` will have a length of 0.  Everytime you try to add to this, you loop through this list (0 times).  You never get to the part where you're actually adding the animal, because its inside a loop that is hit 0 times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move add mthod outside foreach loop

```
 public bool AddAnimal(Animal animal)
    {
        bool status = false;
        foreach (Animal TempAnimal in animalList)
        {
            if (TempAnimal.ChipRegistrationNumber == animal.ChipRegistrationNumber)
            {
                status = false;
            }
            else
            {
                status = true;

            }
        }
   if(status)
 animalList.Add(animal);
        return status;
    }
```

Comment: Oh my god.. duuuuuuuuude, that is such a basic mistake.. can't believe I fell for that. I was about to bash my head against the wall.. Thanks a lot!

Comment: But then you don't enforce the rule _you cannot add another animal with that specific ChipNumber_

Comment: @user2966741 It could happen to anyone :)

Comment: I was about to make a comment about that, I just checked it, and it's true Alex. when I make a second animal with the same number, it will just overwrite the details of the chipnumber.

Comment: Yes That check I have not added....I will update it but with my answer I wanted to point why the list is empty as it is inside foreach loop..

Answer (score 1):

Because you list is empty after creation and when you add first animal `foreach` never executes, becase there is nothing in list. Replace with:

```
public bool AddAnimal(Animal animal)
{
    bool status = true;
    foreach (Animal TempAnimal in animalList)
    {
        if (TempAnimal.ChipRegistrationNumber == animal.ChipRegistrationNumber)
        {
            status = false;
        }
        else
        {
            status = true;
        }
    }
    if (status)
    {
        animalList.Add(animal);
    }
    return status;
}
```

Using linq we can make it shorter:

```
public bool AddAnimal(Animal animal)
{
    if (!animalList.Any(a => a.ChipRegistrationNumber == animal.ChipRegistrationNumber))
    {
        animalList.Add(animal);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: ``if(status)`` in 1st block does not look correct to me, give a try, you said yourself when list empty foreach will not execute, so ``bool`` variable will always be false

Comment: @EhsanSajjad if `status == true` we can add new animal, if `status == false`, so we trying to add duplicated animal and it's forbidden.

Comment: and when we are adding animal first time, and list is empty,then??

Comment: @EhsanSajjad oh, i see. i thought, it was initialized as `true`, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `status` at all. Simple is better.

```
public bool AddAnimal(Animal animal)
{
    foreach (Animal TempAnimal in animalList)
        if (TempAnimal.ChipRegistrationNumber == animal.ChipRegistrationNumber) return false;
    animalList.Add(animal);
    return true;
}
```

It's an equivalent of having 2 methods:

```
public bool IsDuplicate(Animal animal)
{
    foreach (Animal TempAnimal in animalList)
        if (TempAnimal.ChipRegistrationNumber == animal.ChipRegistrationNumber) return true;
    return false;
}
public bool AddAnimal(Animal animal)
{
    if (IsDuplicate(animal)) return false;
    animalList.Add(animal);
    return true;
}
```

`Add` returns true if the item has been added, and false when a duplicate exists, so the item has **not** been added.

Comment: The part that I don't get here is that if you use the "if" statement, you will return "false" if it's true. 

Afterwards you add the animal, but you still return "true".

Comment: I have checked the code, it does work. but could you perhaps clarify a bit?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, mate! Appreciated